# Weird :active behavior in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, css-selectors

I'm having an issue with IE8 where when an image is clicked inside of a link, the :active selector is not being triggered by IE.

### Example:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/pulpit.jpg"></a>
```

**CSS:**

```css
a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #F00;
}
a:hover {
    border-color:#0F0;
}
a:active {
    border-color:#00F;
}
```

**Live demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Faw4z/1/)**

When clicking the area around the image, the link acts normally, but when clicking the image itself, it fails to update.

Any ideas on why this is happening and if there are any workarounds? Since it is mostly working I don't mind appending some JavaScript if needed.

Comment: Apparently with your example, in IE7 the :active state is kept forever after click, in IE8 it doesn't trigger at all.

Comment: A bit random but try setting the image to display:block

Comment: Well how about that, setting the image to display:block worked perfect! If you add that in as answer I'll pick it ASAP. Thanks!

Comment: EDIT: Nevermind, stupid me forgot I was in Chrome so of course it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It may work better if you put the states on the img, but I can't get rid of the outline. http://jsfiddle.net/wSp7J/3/